# How to predict how much space a VACUUM FULL would reclaim?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, postgresql-12

Is there a way to determine in advance how much disk space a `VACUUM FULL` on a particular table would return to the OS? Therefore you can decide whether it's worth the cost in doing so.

Bonus if there's a simple query to do this for every table in a database/server (rather than doing each one separately).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the `pgstattuple` extension to get the amount of free space.

So you could run

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass AS table_name,
       s.table_len AS size,
       dead_tuple_len + s.approx_free_space AS reclaimable
FROM pg_class AS t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL pgstattuple_approx(t.oid) AS s
WHERE t.relkind = 'r'
ORDER BY (s.dead_tuple_len::float8 + s.approx_free_space::float8)
       / (s.table_len::float8 + 1.0) DESC;
```

where `size` and `reclaimable` are in bytes.

Be warned that this query is somewhat expensive.

That should give a pretty good estimate of the space that can be reclaimed, but in practice it will be slightly less, because

1. there is always some free space in each 8kB block that is too small to fit another row
2. some of the dead tuples might not be reclaimable if you have long running transactions

Comment: @OrangeDog Worked for me without quoting `table` (now called `table_name` in the current edit).

Comment: @Colin'tHart I think my client is more strict than necessary about quoting keywords.

Comment: Can I confirm that this also means there can be around `reclaimable` bytes of new updates added without increasing the disk usage (assuming there has been a non-full vacuum)? Or is it likely to be a lot less than that?

Comment: No, because I included `dead_tuple_len`. The free space is `approx_free_space`.